# Change HyperLink Text in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, hyperlink

I've a column as Hyperlink data-type. So, the data in this column are as:

- http://google.com
- http://facebook.com
- http://stackoverflow.com

I want the text of the hyperlink to be changed to just 'Site' so that each record would be named 'Site' but the link would be still there like:

- [Site](http://google.com)
- [Site](http://facebook.com)
- [Site](http://stackoverflow.com)

Note that each item above is written as 'Site' but the hyperlink is different. Any way to achieve it in MS Access?
I can do it manually by modifying hyperlink text and address for each records, however, I have thousands of such items in the database so I need something not manual.

Comment: show your code  .. please

Answer (score 0):

As a one-time update you can add 'site' before the actual web address in your hyperlinked field.  E.g. `www.google.com` would become `site#www.google.com#`